# Is it possible to create a variable variable from a back reference in php?

Tags: php, variables, regex

Suppose I have this:

```
$t = "This %var% should be replaced";
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', "$1", $t);
```

What that does is replace the %var% for var, so the text becomes:

```
This var should be replaced.
```

But what I want to do is have a variable named $var, and then replace "%var%" with the value of $var.

We know that we can create variable variables like this:

```
$foo = "one";
$$foo = "two"
echo $one; //prints "two"
```

If you don't know about this, then you might not be able to answer my question. But you can read more about variable variables on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Well, that does not work in this case. If I do this:

```
$t = "This %var% should be replaced";
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', $"$1", $t);
```

I get an error.

I also tried like this:

```
$t = "This %var% should be replaced";
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', ${$1}, $t);
```

And I get another error.

The question is: how would I create a variable variable to replace %var% with the value of $var?

Some of you might ask why not just do this:

```
$t = "This %var% should be replaced";
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', $var, $t);
```

The reason is simple. The text I have is more complex than that. Lets make it more fun, shall we?

```
$text = "This %var% should be replaced, just like this %foo%;
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', "$1", $text);
```

As you can see, we need to replace %var% with the value of $var, and %foo% with the value of $foo.

I already solved the problem, but in a different way. But I am still wondering how it would be possible to solve it in this way, since the code is more readable. If it is not possible to solve it, then why?

---

Thanks for al your answers ans interest. Like I said I already solved the problem in a different way, and yes, I used preg_repace_callback. I am not looking for a solution to the problem, but for an explanation on why it is not possible to create a variable variable out of the backreference. I'm sorry if my question was confusing, or badly written and made you guys think I was still looking for a solution on how to achieve my goal.

If you wish to see how I solved it, you can go to my blog, I posted there yesterday about this: http://imbuzu.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/back-references-in-php-how-to-create-variable-variables-using-them/

Again. I am not looking for a way to do this, but rather for an explanation on why it is not possible to do it the way I initially intended. Why is it that you can't  create a variable variable from the backreference?

To the Admins. This reply is a general reply to all the answers above. IF you are going to edit it and add it as a comment to any of them, please add it to all of them, or at least notify the users of this reply. Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use preg_replace_callback? - as an aside, the above code is not particularly redable given what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What about an associative array?

```
$replacement = array('var' => 'value1',
                     'foo' => 'value2');
$text = "This %var% should be replaced, just like this %foo%";
$newText = preg_replace('/%(.+?)%/', $replacement[$1], $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$var = '[replaced]';

function handler($found)
{
  if ( isset($GLOBALS[$found[1]]) )
    return $GLOBALS[$found[1]];
  else
    return $found[0];
}

$text = 'This %var% should be replaced and this %var2% will not be replaced!';
$newText = preg_replace_callback('/%(.+?)%/', 'handler', $text);

echo $newText;
```

This outputs the following:

> This [replaced] should be replaced and this %var2% will not be replaced!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a small parser with preg_X functions and an eval call. With these ingredients you can cook something like this:

```
<?php
$var = 'world';
$end = '.';
$t = "This %var% should be replaced%end%";

//We should escape " character
$t = str_replace('"','\"',$t);

$php = $t;
do
{
    $orig_php = $php;
    $php = preg_replace('/%([^%]+)%/','$\\1',$t);
} while($php!=$orig_php);

eval('$output="'.$php.'";');

echo($output);

?>
```

It's a tiny template engine